# Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> t’ with actual type ‘Bool’

Tags: haskell, predicate, boolean-expression, modulo

In Haskell,

This works perfectly fine:`(mod 9) 7`. It gives the expected result: remainder when 9 is divided by 7 (**2**).

Similarly, this works too:`(mod 9) 9`. It returns **0**.

This led me to think that `(mod 9 == 0) 9` should return `True`. However, that hasn't been the case: it threw up an error instead.

THE ERROR:

```
<interactive>:62:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> t’
                  with actual type ‘Bool’
    • The function ‘mod 9 == 0’ is applied to one argument,
      but its type ‘Bool’ has none
      In the expression: (mod 9 == 0) 9
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (mod 9 == 0) 9
    • Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:62:1)
```

Please help me understand why `(mod 9 == 0) 9` wouldn't return `True`.

P.S.: I'm convinced that my usage of "return" in Haskell's context is flawed. However, I am just starting out, so please excuse me. (Would be nice if you could correct me if I am, indeed, wrong.)

Comment: Why would it? `mod 9 :: Integral a => a -> a`, while `0 :: Num a => a`.

Comment: You appear to be trying to compose `==` and `mod 9`, which would look like `((== 0) . (mod 9)) 9`.

Comment: Got it! I feel stupid now. On the bright side, Haskell's type system seems so useful in understanding code. Thank you. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Mmm, I wouldn't. I feel like there is a kernel of a good question here; I'm just not sure how it should be worded :).

Comment: `mod 9 == 0` means `(==) (mod 9) 0`, comparing a function (`mod 9`) and a number (`0`). Ignoring that issue, we still have that `(mod 9 == 0) 9` is `(==) (mod 9) 0 9` passing three arguments to `(==)`, which only takes two.

Comment: Saying e.g. "`mod 9 9` should return 0" is very common. You can also say "`mod 9 9` should evaluate to 0" which is better and more common I think, since there's no implication that `mod` fires missiles and incidentally "returns" `0` (where "return" is from the language of mutable registers, stack, pointers, etc). In other contexts you can pronounce `=` as "is"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, it appears that you expect `mod 9 == 0` to be a function that takes an argument, passes it to `mod 9`, then returns the result of the comparison. You can write such an expression, but it's a little more complicated.

```
>>> ((== 0) . (mod 9)) 9
True
```

Here, `(== 0) . (mod 9)` is the composition of two functions, `(== 0)` and `mod 9`. The composed function takes its argument, applies `mod 9` to it, then applies `(== 0)` to the result. (Where `(== 0)` is a short form for `\x -> x == 0`.)